# Is "ORDER BY" necessary in SQL

Tags: sql

So I am looking at this sql

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM
  (SELECT  *
  FROM EVENT
  WHERE  END_DATE  IS NULL
  ORDER BY
    CASE EVENT_TYPE
      WHEN 'E'
      THEN 1
      WHEN 'C'
      THEN 2
      ELSE 3
    END,
    START_DATE ASC
  ) a
```

and i wonder if it give same result every time if we change it to

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM
  (SELECT  *
  FROM EVENT
  WHERE  END_DATE  IS NULL
  ) a
```

Since I want the count only why should I use order ?

Comment: *No* in the context since all you want is to `count` which doesn't depend on order

Comment: _Since I want the count only why should I use order ?_ Exactly! You have the answer yourself

Comment: The `order by` in the derived table is not really sensible to begin with. The only thing that _guarantees_  an order is an `order by` in the final select statement. The database is free to ignore the `order by` inside the derived table altogether.

Comment: @B001 thank you for answer I was looking the application and they used this types of queries for no reason, so I am begineer and wondering if it matter.

Comment: Not only is it unnecessary, but with some database engines, it will throw an error.

Comment: @DanBracuk indeed not working on MSSQL

Comment: `ORDER BY` in subqueries is generally not needed.  Some databases don't even allow it under most circumstances.  A nested `ORDER BY` does not necessarily affect the result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.  If you just want to find the total number of records in the subquery, then the ordering should not matter.  But note that you don't even need a subquery here in your second version:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM EVENT
WHERE END_DATE IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ORDER BY` does not make a difference in your case.

You can make it even shorter:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM EVENT
WHERE END_DATE IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

All you want is to `COUNT` which *doesn't depend* on order. You can further simplify the query into

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM EVENT
WHERE END_DATE IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Not necessary to add order by because you use count function so result will always return same.

Comment: My vote put your reputation over 50.  You owe me a beer.